# Can an unmarried man take sansyas?

Tags: sanyasi

Can an unmarried man take sanyas ?

Many scriptures say marrying and having a son is compulsory in life. So, one must have a son before taking sansyas , Is it true ?

There is an example of one [Jaratkaru](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaratkaru) in Mahabharata ,who had become ascetic without marrying . Then one day he saw his ancestors falling from heaven to hell . His ancestors told him (Jaratkaru) to marry and have a son first then become ascetic so that their family line don't die otherwise they will fall to hell.

Comment: 'Many people say one should marry & have a son before taking sannyas' - I doubt whether those people know about Adi Shankara

Comment: @AnubrataBit I have edited the post.

Comment: Yes, Om Swami is an example of this.You can know more about him here https://os.me/

Comment: Sanyasa is all about "not marrying" only and "renouncing" everything in search of God.

Comment: Yes they can, and yes they have. Many authoritative acharyas in both advaitin and sri vaishnava sampradayas have taken sannyasa without marrying.

Comment: Yes, the child prodigy Adi Shankaracharya is an example.

Comment: @AnubrataBit - rather, i think that those people doubt whether *those* people *ARE* Adi Shankara. it is heavily discouraged to take directly. if someone is even in the position where he is asking whether or not he should do something, that means he is in doubt, and that means he has to do the safe way.

Comment: @mar There are numerous sanyasis who didn't marry many of which are great saints meaning it is really dharmic.

Comment: @YOuwillnotknow - and if you ask any them for advice whether to marry or not, they will all say 'marry' - because they know that someone who is asking for advice is not fit for direct sanyas. those who are fit to take direct sanyas won't have the doubt of whether they should marry or not. there are 2 things here - whether direct sanyas is dharmic or not. and whether a person should take direct sanyas or not. direct sanyas is dharmic. but if a person ASKS whether he should take direct sanyas, the answer is no.